# Zend Framework 2 which is faster? module.config.php or Module.php?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

For a very long project that I need every bite of memory..

I know how autoload of zf2 works, is Module.php loaded before module.config, but that's nothing about performance between those two declarations.

which of those one are more performance than the another? How about caching possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZF2 has built-in support for caching your module configs, which makes them load faster. However, this doesn't work if the configs contain anonymous functions (since these can't be cached). So the rule of thumb is: put everything in `module.config.php` except your anonymous functions, which you put in the module class. If you want to squeeze everything you can out of your app, don't use anonymous functions for module configuration at all.